# LinearLayout with LayoutWeight not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I have the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/color_brand"
                android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:background="@color/color_white">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@color/color_black"
        android:layout_below="@id/top">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:background="@color/color_white"
        android:layout_below="@id/middle">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want a 40-20-40 split between the layouts, and I've tried everything, but nothing seems to work. I've tried adding an empty view in the linear layouts, I've given the views in the linear layout the weight, but nothing is working. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just change your parent layout from RelativeLayout to LinearLayout. It will work

Comment: Weights do not work on RELATIVE LAYOUT as parent, you need to use LINEAR LAYOUT as parent. –

Comment: Thanks guys. I can't believe I didn't get that.

Comment: Use Linear Layout as parent View.It will work.Relative layout dose not support weight.

Comment: Try this `weightSum=100` with 20-40-20 comibination

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid parent Layout is `RelativeLayout` so `weightsum` will not work with it. He has to change the parent layout to `LinearLayout` with vertical or horizontal orientation or has to use `PercentRelativeLayout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your main root parent to `LinearLayout` and give it a vertical orientation. RelativeLayout don't support `weightsum`, as you see in your code you are defining `0dp` for height so you have to make your root view LinearLayout with vertical orientation to make weightage work.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/color_brand"
            android:weightSum="100">

     --------
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/color_brand">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
   >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/middle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:background="@color/color_black"
    android:layout_below="@id/top"

    >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
       />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
    android:layout_below="@id/middle"

   >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Your parent is Relative layout that why doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

`WeightSum` only work with the `LinearLayout`. So you have to change your parent `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout`.

So Change your this code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/color_brand"
                android:weightSum="100">
```

to this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/color_brand"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:orientation="vertical">
```

> Note : add `orientation` in the `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

`android:weightSum` is not an attribute of `RelativeLayout` it is an attribute of `LinearLayout`. So you can change the parent layout to `LinearLayout` or you can use [`PercentRelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

code snippet

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove your Relative Layout OR change it to Linear with your orientation. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_below="@id/top">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:layout_below="@id/middle">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Use this will solve your issue. And one more thing when your want to manage your layout according to weight then you have to use LINEAR LAYOUT because the weight concept is not working in RELATIVE LAYOUT.

Answer (score 1):

You must have to take LinearLayout as parent for use weightSum because,RelativeLayout don't support weightSum.
Now you have to take LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout.
You have to write your CODE like below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@color/color_brand"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:background="@color/color_white">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/top"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@color/color_black">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/middle"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:background="@color/color_white">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I thin you have to Replace Relativelayout with Linearlayout.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34583453)

Answer (score 0):

Try This For 20-40-20

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_below="@id/top">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_below="@id/middle">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Output:**
[image]

Try this for 40-20-40

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_below="@id/top">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_below="@id/middle">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Output**
[image]